# Integrate Google Analytics Tracking Into IOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, tracking

I would like to Integrate Google Analytics Tracking into my IOS APP.

I have integrated Google Analytics Library and Add It To my Application.

cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/

into my code to tracking my view contact

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.trackPageView = @"Contact Screen";
    //
}
```

A have this error **"Property 'TrackPageView' not found on object of the type 'ContactViewController'"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the wrong property (`trackPageView`) in your `viewDidLoad:` where you should actually be setting the `trackedViewName` property. The code should be as follows:

```
self.trackedViewName = @"Contact Screen";
```

Also in your header (`.h`) file, make sure your `@interface` inherits from the `GAITrackedViewController` class like so:

```
@interface YourContactScreenController : GAITrackedViewController
```

Comment: and in the .h `filename: GAITrackedViewController`

Comment: Yes in the Header (`.h`) file, your class must be a subclass of the GAITrackedViewController class, updated the answer to confirm

Comment: Nowadays is actually called screenName

Answer (score 14):

Today I got the same error, and despite what the setup documentation stated, the property is called `screenName`. so Just write this line in your `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.screenName = @"A name";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Automatic Screen Tracking then you have to do this way:

**@Objective C:**

1. Add #import "GAITrackedViewController.h" into XXX.h file
2. extending current class from GAITrackedViewController [Eg. @interface ClockViewController : GAITrackedViewController]
3. Add this line into XXX.m file's viewDidLoad() method 
   self.screenName = @"Login";

**Note:** Hope you initialize and configured GAI properly into your project.